# Android Request Header Range: bytes=207358401-414716804 , corrupts files?

Tags: android, video, byte, httpurlconnection

I am trying to download a 600MB video file from server using HttpURLConnection. So i have used "range" header to download the file in 3 parts and prepared three separate video file after downloading all the bytes.

**MyCode:**

```
    try{

     URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
     connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "");
     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "LibHttp/1.3.8");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=414716804-622075205");
     connection.connect();

     input = connection.getInputStream();

     byte data[] = new byte[4096];

     int count =0;

       while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

            String path = "/sdcard/test.flv";
            saveTofile(data,path,count);

       }   

   } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(SampleThread.TAG+" Download Exception   "+e.toString());
   }  


public void saveTofile(byte[] data,String path,int count){

    OutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(path),true);

        // Writes bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream

        fos.write(data,0,count);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while writing file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the streams using close method
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

But while playing :

Part - 1 : Range: bytes=0-207358401   // Plays fine //

Part - 2 : Range: bytes=207358401-414716804 // File got corrupted not playing //

Part - 3 : Range: bytes=414716804-622075205 // File got corrupted not playing //

I am not able to find the problem , why the part-1 video file , plays absolutely  fine but the remaining two not at all playing , saying these files are not video files.

Please suggest me some solution to my issue.

Comment: *I don't able to find the problem* ... use logic ... most of the video format has some headers at the begining of the file ... fx in first part of file you have `"You are not "` and in the second `"an idiot"` ... how would you feel if you would read the second part only?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i didn't get your point , can you please elaborate the concept.

Comment: You will not get 3 video files by simple dividing the bytes from 1 video file ... the video file have some structure

Comment: so is there a way to download a large video files in parts using Range request header.

Comment: you have to concat the downloaded files into one after download ... the easiest way is to write the 2nd and 3rd reaquest to the same file at the end of the file

Answer (score 1):

Byte rage is inclusive, not offset-length. Using the following ranges should work

Part - 1 : Range: bytes=0-207358401

Part - 2 : Range: bytes=207358402-414716804

Part - 3 : Range: bytes=414716805-

Comment: Then something is wrong with your downloader. Look at the two files with a hex editor and find the differences.